# how to remove digits from the end of a rich string in php?

Tags: php, string, replace

my strings format is like these:

```
$number == 1212 || $number == 12 12 || $number == 1 212 ||  ...  
$string="this is an example $number";
$string="<p>this is an example <b>$number<p>";
$string="<p>this is an example $number<p>";
```

I use this code for clean string like this:

```
$string="this is an example 1212";
$newString = preg_replace("/\d+$/","",$String );
echo $newString;
```

But how can I do it for all formats?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex from `/\d+$/` to `/[\s+\d+]{1,}$/`